# Reading in json file from server as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a small javascript web application that reads in a hardcoded string in json format as follows (this is inside the script itself):

```
root = {
    "name": "John", "imageURL":"images/root.png","id":"1",
        "children": [
             {"name": "project", "imageURL":"cool.png","id":"2",
             "children":[{"name": "ideas", "imageURL":"object1.png","id":"3"},
                      {"name": "boards", "imageURL":"object2.png","id":"46"}
]},
]
};
```

D3.js then uses this to render its image. Instead I would like to read this json from a file.json sitting on the server (same directory as the web app).  I assume I must use AJAX for this. I tried this:

```
var output = "";
$.ajax({
url: "file.json",
type: 'Get',
dataType: "json",
success: function (result) {
    output = result; 
}
});
```

But nothing comes from this.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I needed something like that, I've used [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), which is a shorthand to what you want.

You can use it like that:

```
$.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
    // Do something with your data
});
```

But, first of all, check your JSON. The JSON you shared is invalid, because it has a comma that shouldn't be there.

I always use validators like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to be sure about that.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The file.json needs to be a valid json file, replace it's content:

```
{
    "name": "John", "imageURL":"images/root.png","id":"1",
        "children": [
             {"name": "project", "imageURL":"cool.png","id":"2",
             "children":[{"name": "ideas", "imageURL":"object1.png","id":"3"},
                      {"name": "boards", "imageURL":"object2.png","id":"46"}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes you were right...json was also an issue. Thank you.

Comment: You could use this json with your javascript (using $.ajax();). Would work too.